# Errors with tree construct by [ape]

Tags: r, phylogeny, phyloseq, ape, ape-phylo

I am trying to plot an MSA tree for my nucleotide sequences. I used toparslan's script. It worked on other files but with the current file, it won't work.
Error on distance information? How do I fix this?

```
> [1] "DNAbin"
dnbin<-dist.dna(nbin, model = "K80") #computing distance by ape package with K80 model derived by Kimura (1980)
tree<-njs(dnbin)
**Error in njs(dnbin) : 
  distance information insufficient to construct a tree, cannot calculate agglomeration criterion**
```

Help would be appreciated!

```
nbinmat<-as.matrix(labels(nbin)) #extraction of the sample names
nbin
class(nbin)
dnbin<-dist.dna(nbin, model = "K80") #computing distance by ape package with K80 model derived by Kimura (1980)
tree<-njs(dnbin) #error comes out here!!
dnbin
```

this is the code I used based on toparslan's script. No changes were made. Error pops out on the `tree<-njs(dnbin)` part

Comment: We cannot help you without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please, provide data and code that reproduce the error. Likely, the problem will be in the data, but there is no way to provide feedback without the data. Also, what is toparslan's script?